# Navigation Components Child NavHost Fragments' view not shown in Parent NavHost Fragment View

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am working on a project which has 2 **NavHost Fragments**. The **First/Parent NavHost Fragment** is attached to the **Main Activity** XML file and shows destinations like Login Fragments and Register Fragment based on a **Parent Navigation Graph**.

Now when a user signs in, new **Navhost Fragment or Child Navhost Fragment** which is attached to another XML file and associated with another **Navigation Graph or Child Nav Graph** Kicks in.

The problem ***I'm facing is instead of showing the second view, that is; the view associated with the child NavHost Fragment xml file**, the app shows **child Nav Graph destinations within the Parent NavHost Fragment***.
It **completely ignores the XML of Child NavHost Fragment file**.

**Main Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Child Fragment Container XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_24dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:translationZ="@dimen/dimen_1dp"
            app:elevation="@dimen/dimen_0dp">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nestedNavHost"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/restaurant_nav_graph" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawerNavView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_view_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As in the code above, **the Toolbar, Drawer Layout, Padding etc in the child navhost xml file is completely ignored**

Any help would be appreciated to resolve the issue.

Comment: This isn't how you are supposed to do login with the Navigation Component as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login) and the [Navigating Navigation video](https://youtu.be/09qjn706ITA).

Comment: Issue is not with the **sign in but with the toolbar**. **The toolbar needs to act based on some fragments after logging in**. Tried adding the toolbar in main activity xml file but **issue occurs with managing scroll flags and layout behavior programmatically with different fragments**. In some fragment the toolbar needs to be transparent. When **toolbar is transparent, the fragments complete hides the toolbar and draws over it**. So thought of working this way.

Comment: The documentation also covers [supporting different toolbars](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#support_app_bar_variations).

Comment: Already read the documentation, watched videos, did codelabs projects but it is not something associated with the documentation. The working is somewhat related with **full layout screen, consuming insets, handling status bar color based on some fragment, managing the scroll flags and layout behavior, toolbar color etc**. Trying to figure out a work around . Will post the code if not able to figure out. Thanks

Comment: If you follow the documentation, none of those things are an issue. If you have a specific question about one of those things when you are following the approaches in the documentation, please do link it here.

Comment: Sure. Will post a new question if not able to solve the problem. Thanks for the comments and guidance.